# Error (10500): VDHL code line 88 (Quartus)

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, vhdl, quartus

we appear to be having an issue with the following code. The error we're getting goes:

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at pract3.vhd(88) near text "PORT"; 
>   expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("port" is a reserved
>   keyword), or a concurrent statement

We're new to Quartus so we don't have no clue what this is supposed to mean.

Here's our code

LIBRARY  ieee;
USE  ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
LIBRARY  work;
ENTITY  pract3  IS
PORT
(
    clk      :   IN    STD_LOGIC;
    I_0      :   IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 TO 3);
    I_1      :   IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 TO 3);
    I_2      :   IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 TO 3);
    I_3      :   IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 TO 3);
    Oper     :   IN    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2  DOWNTO  0);
    act_dis1:   OUT   STD_LOGIC;
    act_dis2:   OUT   STD_LOGIC;
    act_dis4:   OUT   STD_LOGIC;
    act_dis3:   OUT   STD_LOGIC;
    C_out    :   OUT   STD_LOGIC;
    --D         :   OUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 TO 1);
    display :   OUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6  DOWNTO  0);
    oper_led:   OUT   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2  DOWNTO  0)
);
END  pract3;
ARCHITECTURE  bdf_type  OF  pract3  IS

COMPONENT  Practica2
PORT
(
    clk     : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    I0      : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 TO 3);
    I1      : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 TO 3);
    I2      : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 TO 3);
    I3      : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 TO 3);
    dec     : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 TO 3);
    --D       : OUT  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 TO 1);
    sal     : OUT  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6  DOWNTO  0));
END  COMPONENT;

COMPONENT  arithmetic_circuit
PORT
(
    C_in   : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    A      : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15  DOWNTO  0);
    B      : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15  DOWNTO  0);
    S      : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1  DOWNTO  0);
    C_out : OUT  STD_LOGIC;
    G      : OUT  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15  DOWNTO  0)
);
END  COMPONENT;
COMPONENT  binary_to_bcd
GENERIC
(
    bits    : INTEGER  := 16;  --bits of the  binary  input
    digits : INTEGER  := 4    --number  of BCD  digits  to  convert  to
);
PORT
(
    clk      : IN   STD_LOGIC; --sys clk
    reset_n : IN   STD_LOGIC;
    ena      : IN   STD_LOGIC; --enable
    binary   : IN   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(bits -1  DOWNTO  0);  --num to  convert
    busy     : OUT  STD_LOGIC; --indicates  conversion  in  progress
    bcd      : OUT  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(digits *4-1  DOWNTO  0) --BCD  number
);
END  COMPONENT;

    SIGNAL   A_in :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15  DOWNTO  0);
    SIGNAL   B_in :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15  DOWNTO  0);
    SIGNAL   BCD :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 TO 15);
    SIGNAL   G :   STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15  DOWNTO  0);

BEGIN
    oper_led  <= Oper;
    b2v_inst_Practica2 : Practica2
PORT MAP
(
    clk => clk ,
    dip_1 => BCD(12 TO 15),
    dip_2 => BCD(8 TO 11),
    dip_3 => BCD(4 TO 7),
    dip_4 => BCD(0 TO 3),
    dec_D0 => act_dis1 ,
    dec_D1 => act_dis2 ,
    dec_D2 => act_dis3 ,
    dec_D3 => act_dis4 ,
    --D => D,
    sal => display
);
PORT MAP //Error is in this line!!!!!!!!!
(
    C_in => Oper(2),
    A => A_in ,
    B => B_in ,
    S => Oper(1  DOWNTO 0),
    C_out => C_out,
    G => G
);
    stbin : binary_to_bcd
PORT MAP
(
    CLK => clk ,
    reset_n => ’1’,
    ena => ’1’,
    binary => G,
    bcd => BCD
);
    A_in(7  DOWNTO  4)  <= I_0;
    A_in(3  DOWNTO  0)  <= I_1;
    B_in(7  DOWNTO  4)  <= I_2;
    B_in(3  DOWNTO  0)  <= I_3;
    A_in (8)   <=   ’0’;
    A_in (9)   <=   ’0’;
    A_in (10)  <=  ’0’;
    A_in (11)  <=  ’0’;
    A_in (12)  <=  ’0’;
    A_in (13)  <=  ’0’;
    A_in (14)  <=  ’0’;
    A_in (15)  <=  ’0’;
    B_in (8)   <=  ’0’;
    B_in (9)   <=  ’0’;
    B_in (10)  <=  ’0’;
    B_in (11)  <=  ’0’;
    B_in (12)  <=  ’0’;
    B_in (13)  <=  ’0’;
    B_in (14)  <=  ’0’;
END  bdf_type;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `port map` is a construct that connects the instance of an `entity` or `component` to `signal`s. There is a `port map` at line 88, but no instance of an `entity` or `component`. (The ports suggest the missing `component` might be `arithmetic_circuit`).

*I am guessing that* you want something like this:

```
some_instance_name : arithmetic_circuit
PORT MAP
(
    C_in => Oper(2),
    A => A_in ,
    B => B_in ,
    S => Oper(1  DOWNTO 0),
    C_out => C_out,
    G => G
);
```

More importantly, you say that it is Quartus that is giving this error. This code would never compile on anything. Quartus is a synthesiser. You only synthesise something when you have got it working, in other words, when you have tested it using a simulator.

Comment: There are also invalid single quotation characters (non ISO8859-1) in the character literals '1' and '0' in the stdbin component instantiation port map aspect and the following assignments to indexed names of A_in and B_in.

Comment: Hi Matthew! Thank you so much for your help. You were completely right about the problem. Nonetheless, we are newbies here, so we are having trouble fixing it. Indeed, the component is arithmetic_circuit, but we don't quite get how to "link" it or make of it an instance of the component. Thank you so much once again.

Comment: @user1155120 Thanks, you were right! We were getting some errors because of those but weren't sure where they came from.

Comment: @user1155120 - there are - I assumed these were an artifact of posting the code here.

Comment: We made it! Thank you @Matthew Taylor

Comment: Literally every one of the single quotes are no iso 8859-1 characters, which says it's likely an editor artifact. A lot of editors can have their character sets constrained (some like Atom will prevent saving a file with non iso 8859-1 characters, and in Atom's case will provide a non-specific error for pasted in characters).